# Visual Studio Database Project Constraints - Table Script or separate file?

Tags: database, visual-studio, database-project

In Visual Studio Database Projects I've seen table constraints being added in 2 different ways:

1. As part of the same script file used to create the table, after the CREATE TABLE statement;
2. In a separate file, kept in a "Tables\Constraints" folder, one constraint per file.

Are there good reasons to do one or the other?

Visual Studio does number 2 when importing a database from SQL Server, so I would guess that's the best way, but I can't see why. From a developer point of view number 1 seems better, as it keeps the table definition and constraints "closer" to each other.

Answer (score 3):

I can only think of reasons to keep them together (#1) for exactly the reasons you mentioned: it keeps the table definition and constraints closer to each other.

Visual Studio used to keep constraints in separate files but stopped that practice in the latest "SQL Server Database Project" template introduced by SQL Server Data Tools (installed in VS 2012 out of the box, and requires a separate download for VS 2010).

Comment: Just to make it easier for when you eventually upgrade to SSDT database projects, pick #1! Or why not use SSDT database projects from the outset?

Answer (score 1):

Strong vote for #1. Separating the constraints from the table scripts makes it a real pain to add non-nullable columns later. When you deploy, the generated ALTER TABLE script will not be able to add a NOT NULL column to a table with existing data, because it doesn't have a DEFAULT constraint. If the constraint is already in the CREATE TABLE script, the ALTER TABLE will use it and everything will just work.